# How to unmute a speaker channel?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, speakers

A few months ago, I needed to mute the left channel, and the easiest way to do it was to use the gnome-volume-control tool. It has stayed muted since.

Since then I've upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10, and the gnome-volume-control tool is nowhere to be found.

I've tried:

- the default mixer panel
- alsamixer
- pavucontrol

None of these work. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Sound settings in 11.10

The Volume Control applet should still be there. In Unity it will be found in the top right panel menu *Sound Settings*. You can also start the application from the command line by running

```
gnome-control-center sound
```

#### Adjust balance

There you will find a slider to adjust sound balance:

[image]

#### Command line

You can also see the channel sound volume settings from the following command

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

This will give you (amongst many additional settings) for each sink:

```
volume: 0:  49% 1:  49%
        0: -18,39 dB 1: -18,39 dB
        balance 0,00
base volume: 100%
             0,00 dB
```

Changing balance from the command line can not be done with `pacmd`. We need to do this with [ALSA mixer](https://superuser.com/a/317297):

```
amixer sset Master 100%,100%
```

Comment: The amixer command did it!